# Getting an error Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I am getting an error for Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32

Code :

```
var @temp
set @temp = "-536885345"

set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("data",1,"date Desc","oid",@temp))
```

here "oid" field is defined as "Number" in my "data" data extension

on execution getting the below error :
Getting an error Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32.

Please help me in fixing this issue.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ampScript, but shouldn't  `set @temp = "-536885345"`  be without double quotes if it's a number ?

Comment: Make sure to mark the answer as correct if it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a string into a number field. Remove the quotes to make it a number.

```
var @temp 
set @temp = -536885345
set @rows = LookupOrderedRows("data",1,"date Desc","oid",@temp))`
```