# Failed to convert parameter value from a string to a Int32 while all values are integers

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, dataextensions

I've encountered an issue while using a LookUp function in AMPscript in an email. I get the error "Failed to convert parameter value from a string to a Int32", when trying to LookUp a value using an id I retrieved from another Data Extension. Our LookUp looks like this:

```
/* this LookUp has no issue, the recommendation1 column has a Numeric datatype */
SET @recommendation1 = LookUp("users", "recommendation1", "subscriberKey", _subscriberkey)

/* The id column in the Productfeed also has a Numeric datatype */
SET @country = LookUp("ProductFeed", "country", "id", @recommendation1)
```

The columns I use for the retrieve and the columns I use for the WHERE clause all have Numeric as datatype, so why am I getting a "cannot parse string to int32" error? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this answer:

[Getting an error Failed to convert parameter value from a String to a Int32](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66991/getting-an-error-failed-to-convert-parameter-value-from-a-string-to-a-int32)

It seems that you are passing a string into a number field before the two lookups in your question..

Comment: Hi Rachid, thanks for your answer. I can't see where we're passing a string from. As the column we want to use in the WHERE clause and the value we use in the WHERE clause are both Numeric in their Data Extensions.

Comment: Can you past all AMScript code? It will be easier to identify the problem..